# ¿Cómo recuperar la vista File Explorer en el Android Device Monitor?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite

No sé qué ha ocurrido con mi "Android Device Monitor"...!!! He cerrado la pestaña correspondiente al File Explorer del Android Device Monitor (Tools - Android - Android Device Monitor) y no consigo recuperarla.

Dentro del Android Device Monitor, la opción Window - Show view - Android - File Explorer (botón OK) no produce ningún resultado. De hecho, ni esa opción ni ninguna de las otras (Devices, LogCat...)

¿Alguien ha tenido el mismo problema y lo ha solucionado?

Answer (score 1):

Primeramente:

`Tools` > `Android` > `Android Device Monitor`

después dentro de `Android Device Monitor`:

`Window` > `Show View` > Eliges `File Explorer`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En cuanto al problema me parece que es raro pero he visto suceder lo mismo, lo que realizamos fue desconectar el dispositivo o reiniciar Android Studio, me parece que es algún tipo de problema con el ADB.